# How to avoid state URL lost when the page was refreshed using next-usequerystate with Nextjs13?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I using next-usequerystate library with Next Js 13, my problem is that when I refresh the page the state on url is lost .
This is the url:

```
localhost:3000/?page=1&genres=tree
```

When I refresh the page the URL will be :

```
localhost:3000/
```

But if I check with console.log(page) and console.log(genres) my states I see the data

I think that the URL started on server component so when my client component start with the status the URL is already setted.

This is my code:

```
'use client'
import React from 'react'
import {
  useQueryState,
  parseAsArrayOf,
  parseAsString,
  parseAsInteger,
} from 'next-usequerystate'
import Filters from './Filters'
import ListItem from './ListItem'

const ListProvider = () => {
  const [genres, setGenres] = useQueryState(
    'genres',
    parseAsArrayOf(parseAsString).withDefault([])
  )
  const [pageIndex, setPageIndex] = useQueryState(
    'page',
    parseAsInteger.withDefault(1)
  )

  return (
    <>
      <Filters genres={genres} setGenres={setGenres} />
      <ListItem
        genresFilters={genres}
        setGenres={setGenres}
        pageIndex={pageIndex}
        setPageIndex={setPageIndex}
      />
    </>
  )
}

export default ListProvider
```

I tried to avoid the problem with this solution :

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setGenres(genres)
    setPageIndex(pageIndex)
  }, [])
```

I don't think is a good solution, but it works.

is there anyone having the same problem? Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

it appears there is a hydration issue in `next-usequerystate` package you are using, because when you refresh the page `next-usequerystate` it sets the initial state based on default value. your workaround this issue can be by using the next/router with useEffect of next.js to hydrate after the refresh.

```
const router = useRouter();

const [genres, setGenres] = useQueryState(
    'genres',
    parseAsArrayOf(parseAsString).withDefault([])
);

const [pageIndex, setPageIndex] = useQueryState(
    'page',
    parseAsInteger.withDefault(1)
);


useEffect(() => {
    const { query } = router;
    setGenres(query.genres || []);
    setPageIndex(query.page || 1);
}, [router, setGenres, setPageIndex]);
```